# External Javascript isn't invoking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having issues with external javascript. Here is my basic form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/styles.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Javascript/UserScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Start Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="newUser">
    Email: <input type="text" name="Email"> <br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="Password"> <br/>
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword"> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

If I call the following internally it works just fine. If I call it externally I get nothing.

```
$("#newUser").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    alert('hello world');
});
```

I even made a new file and did a test with something like this just to make sure jquery was working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    alert('hello')
}
```

Comment: Anything in the Error Console (F12)?

Comment: Is that first bit of code inside a document ready handler?

Comment: when you put in external file, is the external file in correct location and is it loading in your firebug view or something? the example runs fine in jsfiddle. So i guess it must be problem with the location of the file.

Comment: When I load up the developer console in chrome it loads just fine. I can see the script and everything. And the .submit code is not in a document.ready function @JLRishe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code inside a document ready handler:

```
$(function () {
    $("#newUser").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

       alert('hello world');
    });
});
```

You can't attach an event to an element before it exists. Your script runs before the `#newUser` element has been parsed and added to the DOM. The `$("#newUser")` in your code is producing an empty set.